# how to sort data table which contains date column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable which contains 1 date column as

```
dttable.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
dttable.Columns.Add("Col2");
dttable.Columns.Add("Col3");
dttable.Columns.Add("Col4");
dttable.Columns.Add("Col5");
```

I am binding this table with gridview after sorting with StartDate, as below

```
dttable.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";
GridView1.DataSource = dttable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

In a gridview I want the date in string format as "dd-MMM-yyyy". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<columns>
  <asp headertext="StartDate" dataformatstring="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" 
       datafield="StartDate"  />
</columns>
```

Comment: Is this possible at runtime/server side?

Answer (score 1):

In aspx file just use following code for startdate column

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="StartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StartDate","{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work.

```
string str="";

for(int i=0;i<dttable.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  str = dttable.rows[i]["StartDate"].toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
  dttable.rows[i]["StartDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyy",null);
}

dttable.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";
GridView1.DataSource = dttable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```